# Calling a Java web service created using Axis from PHP code

Tags: java, php, soap, wsdl, axis

Im trying to call a Java web service created using Axis from PHP code.The webservice is hosted on my LAN. I am able to call the web service successfully using SoapUI. I have the PHP Soap Extension installed.
However,im not sure whether my PHP code is correct. Below is my PHP code.

```
<?php
 $client = new SoapClient('http://machinename/axis/services/Compiere?wsdl');
 $params = array('in0'=> '124','in1'=>'1');
 $result = $client->__SoapCall('createOrder',array($params));
 print $result->createOrderReturn;
?>
```

The WSDL is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://compservice.com" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://compservice.com" xmlns:intf="http://compservice.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->

   <wsdl:message name="createOrderRequest">

      <wsdl:part name="in0" type="xsd:int"/>

      <wsdl:part name="in1" type="xsd:int"/>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="createOrderResponse">

      <wsdl:part name="createOrderReturn" type="xsd:string"/>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="OrderServiceInt">

      <wsdl:operation name="createOrder" parameterOrder="in0 in1">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:createOrderRequest" name="createOrderRequest"/>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:createOrderResponse" name="createOrderResponse"/>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="CompiereSoapBinding" type="impl:OrderServiceInt">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="createOrder">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="createOrderRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://compservice.com" use="encoded"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="createOrderResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://compservice.com" use="encoded"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="OrderServiceIntService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:CompiereSoapBinding" name="Compiere">

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://nuca232/axis/services/Compiere"/>

      </wsdl:port>

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Is my PHP code correct ?

Please help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try the direct mode?

```
 <?php
 $client = new SoapClient('http://machinename/axis/services/Compiere?wsdl');
 $params = array('in0'=> '124','in1'=>'1');
 $result = $client->createOrder( $parms );
 print_r($result);
```

Instead of using $client->__SoapCall('createOrder',array($params));

[As the manual says: "Usually, in WSDL mode, SOAP functions can be called as methods of the SoapClient object"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php)